# Error after updating Angular from 12 to 13: This constructor is not compatible with Angular Dependency Injection because its dependency is invalid

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, ivy

I'm facing a weird problem after updating Angular to version 13.

This is the error that I have for plenty of directives/pipes/modules and I believe I missed something in the configuration file, or screwed something with webpack update.

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: This constructor is not compatible with Angular Dependency Injection because its dependency at index 0 of the parameter list is invalid.
> This can happen if the dependency type is a primitive like a string or if an ancestor of this class is missing an Angular decorator.

This is how the construtor of the directive looks like:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[sfTranslate]'
})
export class JhiTranslateDirective implements OnChanges, OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() sfTranslate: string;
  @Input() translateValues: any;

  private readonly directiveDestroyed = new Subject<never>();

  constructor(private configService: JhiConfigService, private el: ElementRef, @Optional() private translateService: TranslateService) {}
  ...rest of code...
}
```

So I go into `JhiConfigService` because it is at 0 index position:

```
@Injectable()
export class JhiConfigService {
  CONFIG_OPTIONS: JhiModuleConfig;

  constructor(moduleConfig?: JhiModuleConfig) {
    this.CONFIG_OPTIONS = {
      ...new JhiModuleConfig(),
      ...moduleConfig
    };
  }

  getConfig(): JhiModuleConfig {
    return this.CONFIG_OPTIONS;
  }
}
```

And this service I put into providers array of some module.

I had a similar issues with other service and the way how I got rid off this one specific error is weird.. I just removed `providedIn: 'root'` from the injectable decorator and put that service into providers array - in the case from the example as you can see it didn't help so I guess that is not the reason. I'm wondering what could change (in gerenral it was update from Angular 8 to 14 but we noticed that problem between 12 and 13) between this Angular version, I can't find any information about it in the documentation/update guide.

I believe removing `inRoot` from decorator and adding service in module's providers is not a solution. Can someone help me?

Comment: I suspect JhiModuleConfig might actually be the problem. What does that contain?

Comment: Are you sure that `private el: ElementRef` is not the problem?